# Disable P4V Auto Refresh of “Reconcile Offline Work” If Window is Left Open

Tags: perforce, p4v

If I do "Reconcile Offline Work" in P4V, after a while the reconciling will finish and a window will eventually pop up showing the files that were modified, added, or removed.  Sometimes I know the reconciling will take a few minutes or more based on the huge number of files in the directory, so I move on and start working on something else, and I expect that the reconciling will be done when I return later.  However, sometimes, when I go back to P4V several minutes later, I see the window filled in with all of the modified, added, and removed files for a brief moment before they get blanked out and the scan seems to start all over again.

This can be quite aggravating since I'm trying to avoid having to sit around and wait for the reconciling to complete, but I end up having to wait for multiple reconciles when I only want to do it once.

Any ideas as to what causes this or how to turn off this repeated reconciling when I only want to reconcile once?

I'm using the "2014.3" version.

Comment: That's weird! You're sure that it's doing all the file analysis multiple times, not just re-printing the messages? I wonder if it's detecting that your P4V windows were hidden, and now they have been brought to the foreground, and hence it is somehow re-performing the last command. Can you reproduce this behavior with P4V operations other than Reconcile Offline Work?

Comment: It adds another "p4 reconcile -m -f <dir>" to the logs, and if there are any newly modified files (files that weren't modified before the previous reconcile), it adds those when it is done re-scanning.  It might only occur if additional files change... but I'd still like to not have the addition reconcile calls even is additional files get modified.  I'll test it out some more... it seems pretty easy to reproduce over and over again.

Comment: Kinda sad that this bug is the default, still!  When working on a large project (or a slow server) where the reconcile scan can take several minutes, it will never finish but instead keep restarting.  If you reconcile anything else substantial, it's an invisible time limit where you have to speed through the reconcile dialog before it restarts itself.

Comment: This function is total BS. It wipes out all of your checkboxes every minute. If I want to refresh the list, I'll do it myself. Who are they to know when the list needs to be refreshed? What makes 1 minute the right time interval anyway? Bunch of crap.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I did a bit of additional searching on this and finally stumbled upon the answer!

This is bug #70465: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4vnotes.txt

> ```
> #1171326 (Bug #70465)
>     There is now a preference to disable global refresh affecting the Reconcile 
>     Offline Work dialog. Default is to continue allowing global refresh to
>     update the dialog. The preference can be found on the Behavior page in
>     preferences.
> ```

Updating to a newer version (2015.1 or newer) will allow me to disable the global refresh in the Preferences/Behavior menu.

[image]

Comment: Why the hell would anyone want this behavior? This is like having a checkbox for "Fix the bug". Oh Perforce, you never cease to amaze me.

Comment: Is this always on in the later clients (2018.x+) or was this option moved somewhere?